# Solving regression problem via conjugate gradient

Tags: regression, svd, conjugate-gradient

Suppose I have a system of linear equations $X\beta = y$, with matrix $X_{n,d}$ and vector $y_n$, where $n>d$. In other words, an overdeterimined system of equations. The OLS solution is:

$\beta = (X^T X)^{-1}X^Ty$

which is the same solution found solving the system of equations via SVD:

$X\beta = y$

$U\Sigma V^T\beta = y$

$\beta = V\Sigma^{-1}U^T y$

Mi question is, if I use an iterative method to solve for $\beta$, for example, the conjugate gradient method, am I going to approximate this solution or a different one with different properties?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you intend to use the conjugate gradient method to solve the linear system $A\beta = X^T y$, where $A=X^TX$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite. According to the post below, the conjugate gradient method in this case is supposed to converge to the minimum norm solution.

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35239/what-happens-when-i-use-a-conjugate-gradient-solver-with-a-symmetric-positive-se

Comment: Why multiply both sides by $X^T$? Does CG not work with overdetermined systems?

Comment: CG requires a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.

Comment: Oh ok. And by minimum norm, you mean minimum residual norm? $\lVert y - X\beta \rVert_2$ (in other words, OLS).